# Making JPopupMenu's submenus heavyweight

Tags: swing, popup, submenu

http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/mixing/index.html advices how to make `JPopupMenu`s heavyweight. Just set the property:

```
setLightWeightPopupEnabled(false);
```

It works fine, but if I have submenus in the popup, implemented as `JMenu` items, they don't seem to inherit the popup's heavy weight. `JMenu` doesn't have a method to make itself heavyweight, and using an AWT `Menu` isn't an option, since I want to put Swing items into it.

How do I make the submenus heavyweight, too?

Comment: +1 nice one, this saved me time.

Comment: Dude, it seems your update is a perfectly valid answer to your question, so move the update to answer, and mark the answer as accepted, it will make the internet (and more especially Stackoverflow) a little better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to be a Swing bug. Setting the global property

```
JPopupMenu.setDefaultLightWeightPopupEnabled(false);
```

works! Also submenu `JMenu` items go heavy, as they should. Obviously the per-instance method `setLightWeightPopupEnabled` should work similarly, but it doesn't.

I filed a bug (Bug Id: [7005406](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7005406)) on this, but I leave the question here just in case that someone else bumps on this. So the solution is to use the global setting until the bug gets fixed.